# I am having trouble With Magento Tooltip Multiple Image Labels For Grouped Products, is there any way to fix this?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, labels

I am having trouble with multiple image labels for grouped products on Magento 1.9, is there any way to fix this? I will explain in detail about my issue using screenshots.

For example:

When I hover over here to the correct picture and correct tooltip label, it says: "Apple Crumble" [image]

However, when I clicked to the next picture, and hover over with my mouse, the tooltip label still says "Apple Crumble" which is incorrect. The tooltip label should say "Warm Berry Crumble" from the already typed label in the product > images section on the admin backend for example, but the image label feature does not cover that unfortunately.

[image]

Unfortunately, the label feature in the images section of Magento products on the admin backend only covers the small multiple images thumbnails at the bottom of the preview image, not the hover over picture on the next one on top that is clicked on by the user. Is there anyway to fix this problem by editing a file code that I found in file manager from our Magento installation?

I did find two files in file manager that may need editing from this though:

```
app/design/frontend/default/theme201k/template/ecommerceteam/cloud-zoom/catalog/product/view/media.phtml
skin/frontend/default/theme201k/css/styles.css
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.